# Ubuntu 14.04 & 16.04 and Acer AO751h boot without Disabled acpi

Tags: boot, lubuntu, shutdown, acpi

I have an old netbook Acer AO751h with Lubuntu 14.04 and due to screen problems I can boot it only with kernel parameter `acpi=off` but this has the following issues:

- When I shut it down and shut down procedure is done I have to press the power off button,
- I cannot get the battery status as well.

So I tried to use the following kernel commands:

```
quiet console=tty1 acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux acer_wmi.blacklist=yes mem=992mb
```

But on boot I get a blank screen. The original problem is that without `acpi=off` I get a "tearing effect" or the screen shows random letters without even booting into Xorg.

Do you fellas have any idea how to fix that?

## Edit 1

I tried:

```
quiet acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux acer_wmi.blacklist=yes mem=992mb
```

And I get a screen with a cursor blinking after a while random letters are being thrown.

I also tried with `mem=1920mb` and some random lines I get over my screen.

## Edit 2

By also removing the `mem=992mb` I get the 'tearing effect' on Xorg the parameters I tried are:

```
quiet acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux acer_wmi.blacklist=yes
```

## Edit 3

I also tried the same with Lubuntu 16.04.2 and still got same problems only `acpi=off` seems to work. Is there a way to disable only the backlight?

Comment: Try a more recent kernel or version of Ubuntu

Comment: With Lubuntu 16.04.2 Live USB I still have similar errors only boots with `acpi=off`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both Lubuntu 16.04.2 and Lubuntu 14.04 you should boot with the `nolapic` boot parameter. In my case with the same netbook it booted like a charm. Also provides full shutdown/reboot functionality as well.

So the correct parameter boot order is:

```
quiet splash nolapic
```

You can do it by editing the `GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry into `/etc/default/grub` by:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

(Use Ctrl+X to save)

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```